# Tensor product of separable extensions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In the proof of the  result [Tag 0C2X](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C2X) taken from the stack project, the author proves first that when $k'/k$ is finite separable, then there exists a multiplicative subset $S\subseteq k'\otimes_k k'$ such that $k'\cong S^{-1}(k'\otimes_k k')$, and I can understand this. But then in the general case, he claims that we can write $k'=\bigcup k_i$ where the $k_i$ runs over all finite subextensions over $k$, and take $S=\bigcup S_i\subseteq k'\otimes_k k'$, where $S_i^{-1}(k_i\otimes_k k_i)\cong k_i$, and claim that $S$ is a multiplicative subset such that $S^{-1}(k'\otimes_k k')\cong k'$. Why $S$ is a multiplicative subset?

Comment: Well, the stack project is the worst math website ever. Why do you care of the case $k'/k$ infinite ? There is a natural homomorphism $f:k'\otimes_k k'\to k'$ and $S=f^{-1}((k')^\times)$ is your multiplicative subset.

Comment: And $S^{-1}(k'\otimes_k k')$ is a field because every non-zero element comes from some $S_i^{-1} (k_i\otimes_k k_i)\cong S_i^{-1} k_i[x]/(p_i(x))=q_i(x)^{-1} k_i[x]/((x-a_i)q_i(x))  \cong  k_i$ so it has an inverse there which stays an inverse in $S^{-1}(k'\otimes_k k')$.

Comment: @reuns The worst math website ever? Really?

Comment: @QiZhu Yes, zero examples, zero clues, abstract nonsense everywhere, many flawed arguments, always trying to be general instead of relevant.

Comment: @reuns I'm not sure what you're expecting, the Stacks Project is not a textbook.